# how to synchronize the java file with dynamically generated file?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have created a eclipse plugin which will dynamically generate a text file. When the user right click the method from the package explorer it will generate a new file with the class structure and the method body. I want to synchronize these two files. When the user make some changes in the method inside the java file. It must be updated in the generated file.

Consider a scenario we have java file with 2 methods

```
public Class Calculator{

       public int add(int a ,int b){
              int c=a+b;
              return c;
          }
        public int sub(int a ,int b){
              int c=a-b;
              return c;
         }
 }
```

The user right click the add method from the package explorer and generate the file. The file will be as follows

File name will be generated based on the class name and method name.

Calculator_add.txt:

```
 public Class Calculator{

       public int add(int a ,int b){
              int c=a+b;
              return c;
          }
    }
```

If the user changes the logic in the method it must be reflected in the generated file. How can i achieve this in eclipse. Please give some suggestion. It will be very much helpful.

Comment: You can use `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for changes to workspace resources.

Comment: @greg-449 - Thanks for your response. can you give me algorithm or pseudo code to solve the above problem. I am new to this eclipse plugin field am very much in need of the solution.

Comment: Look at [Responding to resource changes in the Eclipse Workspace](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html)

Comment: @greg-449: is it possible to identify which method content is changed through this IResourceChangeListener.?

Comment: I got the filename where the changes happened .. i want to get the method name or the line number where the changes taken place. how can i get that using the   IIResourceDelta ?

Comment: IResourceDelta does not have any information on what has changed in the file.

Comment: @greg-449 Then ,Is it possible to get the information and the method name which is changed?

Comment: Looks like you can use `JavaCore.addElementChangedListener` to listen for Java model changes which may do what you want - I don't know any more about this.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your valuable response.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure that this should be done this way; what you describe sounds more like a buildstep alike thing for which you mark the methods you want to be included/processed

so i will a bit restructure your original problem and try to give hints for that

- when the user selects a method; the method will be added to a list of toBeCopied things
- add a custom builder or a "generate outputs" menu item from which the process can be launched

  - when it runs, it iterates over the list of toBeCopied and reads all methods

i hope this helps

Comment: Actually i fetched the method content and generated the output file. I need to make changes or update the generated file automatically when the user changes the content in the source file. Is that possible?